# Command to get the module that manages my Network Interface card?

Tags: command-line

I am looking for a command that would show me which module is responsible for managing my network interface. When I use the command`cat /etc/modules` this is what I get [image]

an empty file.

Comment: `/etc/modules` is the place for putting all the external kernel modules that will be loaded at boot time..this is somewhat similar to running `modprobe module_name` to load the module at run time..

Comment: @heemayl ok its clearer now

Comment: Use `sudo lshw -C network | grep -Po "(?<=driver=)[^ ]+"` to get the module (driver) being used to manage your network..

Answer (score 2):

To see the kernal driver that manages your network interface card, type

`sudo lshw -C network` and look at the `driver` entry, or

use:

`lspci -v` and look at the `Kernel driver in use` for your network and Ethernet controller

Edit: If you want to see what are the currently loaded kernal modules and the processes that use them, use `lsmod`

Comment: Precisely `sudo lshw -C network | grep -Po "(?<=driver=)[^ ]+"`

Comment: @Ron i am not looking for the kernel driver but for the loaded  module that manages my network interface card. Perhaps are they synonyms????

Comment: see my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Among other things, you can use `nmcli dev list` command to list all info for your network interfaces. To list for specific interface , use `nmcli dev list iface wlanX`, where wlanx is wireless interface with number. For instance, default is wlan0. If you've ever swapped internal cards or added usb dongle - those would have another name, e.g., my usb dongle is wlan3

To among other things, you can do

`nmcli dev list iface wlan0 | awk '/GENERAL.DRIVER/ {print $2}' >> /etc/modules` to find out the module and append it to `/etc/modules` file right away

Comment: Like my answer ? please leave an  upvote. Solved your problem ? click grey checkmark to accept the answer